# int array sort modifies the array content

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, int

I'm working on codes which deal with arrays of strings and ints.

This one compiles and runs OK, but the content of the array get modified.

The code gives the main result which is the largest number.
But, after the sort process I display the content of the array and one of the elements is modified to 0.
So, what is the reason for this?

Regards,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdint.h>

int main()
{

static uint8_t arr2[]={5,100,-2,75,42},cr=0,ps=1,temp=0;
uint8_t i;

for (i=0;i<sizeof(arr2);i++)
{
    printf("1stloop[%d]\n",i);
    if (arr2[cr]>arr2[ps])
    {
        printf("before change1 cr %d ps %d\n",arr2[cr],arr2[ps]);
        temp=arr2[cr];
        arr2[cr]=arr2[ps];
        arr2[ps]=temp;
        printf("change1        cr %d ps %d\n\n",arr2[cr],arr2[ps]);

        if (arr2[cr-1]>arr2[ps-1])
        {
            printf("before change2 cr %d ps %d\n",arr2[cr-1],arr2[ps-1]);
            temp=arr2[cr-1];
            arr2[cr-1]=arr2[ps-1];
            arr2[ps-1]=temp;
            printf("change2        cr %d ps %d\n\n",arr2[cr-1],arr2[ps-1]);
        }
    }
    cr++; ps++;
}
    for (i=0;i<sizeof(arr2);i++)
{
    printf("contents %d \n",arr2[i]);
}
printf("\nLargest No. in arr2 of arr2 is %d \n",(arr2[sizeof(arr2)]));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're using arr2[cr-1] when cr==0.  Index -1 is outside of your array.  You're also using arr2[ps] when ps == sizeof(arr2) == 5.  Index 5 is also outside of your array.  The largest number you print at the end comes from index 5 -- outside of your array.  When you swapped the largest number into here, i.e., outside of your array, you swapped garbage that happened to be zero into your array.

Comment: Step through the code using a debugger to learn what is really going on.

Comment: Yes thank you, I add printf("OK"); in loops to see where is the problem. It's actually about loop counters and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dry run your code in execution of last step of the for loop values will be `i=4,cr=4,ps=5`.As you can see total elements of arr2[] is 5 but you are trying to compare 5th element with 6th in your code so it will take 6th element as 0 and will execute according to your logic.

So in for loop condition you can make modification.

---

Instead of this `for (i=0;i<sizeof(arr2);i++)`
you can try this `for (i=0;i<sizeof(arr2) && ps<sizeof(arr2);i++)`.

---

This will not modify the entries of array.But as it is unsigned char, Entry of element '-2'  will be considered as '254'.

Comment: I did this code and it works OK! static int8_t arr2[]={5,100,-2,75,42},cr=0,ps=1,temp=0;
 uint8_t i,cnt=sizeof(arr2); 
 printf("array before:\n"); 
 for (i=0;i<cnt;i++)
    {
        printf("%d \n",arr2[i]);
    } 
 temp=arr2[cr];
 arr2[cr]=arr2[ps];
 arr2[ps]=temp;
 printf("array after:\n");
 for (i=0;i<cnt;i++)
    {
        printf("%d \n",arr2[i]);
    }